# How often does Kernel Same-Page Merging (KSM) do a full run?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory-management, system-calls, kvm

I'm trying to get some understanding into how KSM is run. After reading through the documentation: (https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/vm/ksm.txt)
 and this paper detailing its implementation: (https://landley.net/kdocs/ols/2009/ols2009-pages-19-28.pdf)

I understand that KSM will eventually scan all of the memory pages that have been marked as VM_MERGEABLE by madvise and complete a full "KSM Pass". I also understand that the scan is broken up into several "batches" where the kernel thread will scan a number of pages (pages_to_scan: default 100) before going to sleep (sleep_millisecs: default 20) and will continue to do this until all of the VM_MERGEABLE pages have been scanned.

I see that the parameters (pages_to_scan and sleep_millisecs) are passed in to the ioctl(2) call to start scanning, but what I don't understand is how often KSM is run after each full "KSM Pass". I can't seem to find much of any information on this. Is KSM constantly running (i.e. it restarts after each full "KSM Pass") or is there some delay?